# Correct way to handle value change of an input element mapped from array held in state

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm struggling to ensure that form elements created from a mapped array remain controlled by React

I have an array of objects that is passed into a React component through props

```
vehicles: [
    {make: 'make1', model: 'model1'},
    {make: 'make2', model: 'model2'}
]
```

I'm then storing these in state (the purpose of the React component in question is to amend the vehicles array at its source)

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.setState({
        vehicles: this.props.vehicles
    })
}
```

After this I'm mapping through the array to create jsx to be returned in `render()`

```
const vehicles = this.state.vehicles.map((vehicle, index) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <FormGroup row>
                <Col sm={1}></Col>
                <Label for={`make-${index}`} sm={3}>Make</Label>
                <Col sm={7}>
                    <Input type="text" name={`make-${index}`} id={`make-${index}`} data-context="vehicle" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={vehicle.make} readOnly={!this.state.formEnabled} />
                </Col>
                <Col sm={1}></Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup row>
                <Col sm={1}></Col>
                <Label for={`model-${index}`} sm={3}>Model</Label>
                <Col sm={7}>
                    <Input type="text" name={`model-${index}`} id={`model-${index}`} data-context="vehicle" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={vehicle.model} readOnly={!this.state.formEnabled} />
                </Col>
                <Col sm={1}></Col>
            </FormGroup>
        </div>
    );
})
```

However, setting the values this way means that I can't change their state using the `handleInputChange()` function (or even enter text in the input fields in the browser).

Is there a way to keep dynamically created form elements controlled by React? Or is my approach fundamentally flawed?

Comment: you can change the state in `handleInputChange()` by calling setState inside your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the index as a data attribute on the input, and then update the array in your `handleInputChange` function and update the state with the new array. Something like this:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
  const thisVehicleIndex = event.target.dataset.item
  let vehicles = this.state.vehicles
  let thisVehicle = vehicles[thisVehicleIndex]
  // Handle your update thisVehicle, then...
  vehicles[thisVehicleIndex] = thisVehicle
  this.setState({
    vehicles: vehicles
  })
}
```

Your input would look something like this (note the new data-item attribute):

```
<Input type="text" name={`make-${index}`} id={`make-${index}`} data-context="vehicle" data-item={index} onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={vehicle.make} readOnly={!this.state.formEnabled} />
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, just what I was after